# How to refresh view after download file in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am working in MVC. i want to refresh my view after downloading file.

I have tried following code:

```
    Response.Clear()

    Response.ClearHeaders()

    Response.ClearContent()

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "MyFile.txt")

    '  Response.AddHeader("Target", "_self")

    'Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", File.Length.ToString())

    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"

    Response.Flush()

    Dim obytearray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pLicenseFile)
    Dim ostring = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(obytearray)

    Response.BinaryWrite(obytearray)
    Response.[End]()
```

i want to get response at client side. or Is it possible to download in other tab and get back to my current view?

i have tried **Inline** in following line:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Inline; filename=" + "MyFile.txt")
```

But in this case i lost my current view :(

Thanks!

Comment: Is refreshing the View on the client-side a possibility?  This would be trivial with `window.location.reload()`.